# How to parse audit_cmd in auditd logs?

Tags: linux-audit

I have some lines of `auditd.log` that contains the key `audit_cmd` followed by a long string of HEX.

```
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(<TIMESTAMP>): pid=<PID> uid=<UID> auid=<AUID> ses=72940 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
msg='cwd="/home/<account>" cmd=2F62696E2F7368202D63206563686F204<HEX> terminal=pts/2 res=success'
```

How can I parse it?

Note: I might not be always on the machine that originally generated the logs (in some cases I look at logs already forwarded to an Elasticsearch server).

Comment: Can you post an extract of the data you are parsing

Comment: No. I'm not sure what's on it (since I don't know how to parse it) and it might be a security risk to post it online

Comment: found it: `echo "<long hex string in audit_cmd section>" | xxd -r -p` found in https://serverfault.com/a/673720/145823

Comment: @TomKlino you should have considered the other easier answer in your link: `ausearch -i` to have the hex interpreted for you.

Comment: Yes. See the note I've written in the question as to why this is not an ideal solution for me

Answer (score 1):

I were running into the same question as I was collection `auditd.log` via SplunkUniversalForwarder and for investigation in Splunk.

As @[Tom Klino](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30590/tom-klino) already mentioned and discussed under [auditd execve arguments looks like encoded data](https://serverfault.com/questions/673279/auditd-execve-arguments-that-looks-like-encoded-data/), the command string seems to be HEX encoded ASCII.

Therefore it would be possible to decode it via

```
echo "<HEX encoded ASCII string>" | xxd -r -p
```

on the remote log collector (i.e. Splunk) later (and if `xxd` became installed with `vim` ).

A better approach for me seems to be to preprocess the log with `ausearch -if audit.log -i` and collect it with the [Splunk app `rlog.sh`](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/33860/convert-audit-log-uid-to-usernames-using-rlog-sh.html).